# Align text and image on the same line on a list group

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello everyone so i'm making a website as a project and in one of the parts i'm putting a list group with the name of the item and on the right the image of said item. I did it already using Pingendo but the text is not align with the image correctly.

This is the code i have atm:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2"> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center text-lg-left">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="list-group my-3">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
              <div class="w-100">
                <h4 class="mb-1 text-center">Arduino Uno</h4>
              </div>
              <img class="d-block float-right img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="https://pingendo.com/assets/photos/wireframe/photo-1.jpg" width="150" height="150" > </a>
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
              <div class="w-100">
                <h5 class="mb-1 text-center">Breadboard</h5>
              </div>
              <img class="d-block float-right img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="https://pingendo.com/assets/photos/wireframe/photo-1.jpg" width="60" height="60" > </a>
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
              <div class="w-100">
                <h5 class="mb-1 text-center">Product</h5>
              </div>
              <img class="d-block float-right img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="https://pingendo.com/assets/photos/wireframe/photo-1.jpg" width="60" height="60" > </a>
            </a>
          </div>
```

and this is how it looks on the website:

[image]

Basically what i'm trying to do is to put both text and image aligned on the same line so i doesn't look the text on the top and the image below.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might need to `position` your image to fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove '.flex-column'  class form `.list-group-item` and add '.d-flex'.

> also remove duplicate closing `a` tag form your code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2"> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center text-lg-left">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="list-group my-3">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex   align-items-start">
              <div class="w-100">
                <h4 class="mb-1 text-center">Arduino Uno</h4>
              </div>
              <img class="d-block float-right img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="https://pingendo.com/assets/photos/wireframe/photo-1.jpg" width="60" height="60" > </a>
           

            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex    align-items-start">
              <div class="w-100">
                <h5 class="mb-1 text-center">Breadboard</h5>
              </div>
              <img class="d-block float-right img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="https://pingendo.com/assets/photos/wireframe/photo-1.jpg" width="60" height="60" > </a>
          

            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex  align-items-start">
              <div class="w-100">
                <h5 class="mb-1 text-center">Product</h5>
              </div>
              <img class="d-block float-right img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="https://pingendo.com/assets/photos/wireframe/photo-1.jpg" width="60" height="60" > </a>
            
          </div>
```

if you want text and image into center

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2"> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center text-lg-left">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="list-group my-3">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex   align-items-center">
              <div class="w-100">
                <h4 class="mb-0 text-center">Arduino Uno</h4>
              </div>
              <img class="d-block float-right img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="https://pingendo.com/assets/photos/wireframe/photo-1.jpg" width="60" height="60" > </a>
           

            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex align-items-center">
              <div class="w-100">
                <h5 class="mb-0 text-center">Breadboard</h5>
              </div>
              <img class="d-block float-right img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="https://pingendo.com/assets/photos/wireframe/photo-1.jpg" width="60" height="60" > </a>
          

            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex  align-items-center">
              <div class="w-100">
                <h5 class="mb-0 text-center">Product</h5>
              </div>
              <img class="d-block float-right img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="https://pingendo.com/assets/photos/wireframe/photo-1.jpg" width="60" height="60" > </a>
            
          </div>
```